# I am trying to log the props of a parent component in the child component

Tags: reactjs, state, react-props

Im trying to get the props passed to my parent component using this.state.props in my child component.

I have googled everywhere

```
   choice(){
     console.log(this.props.size);
  }

{this.props.size && <DropdownItem onClick={this.choice} className="bg-info">{this.props.size}</DropdownItem>}


this is the parent component
 <DropDown
                      title="Options"
                      special={special}
                      size={size1}
```

Comment: You cannot access the props of the parent component from the child component. Did you mean accessing the props passed from the parent?

Comment: So how would change the state using the properties i passed in the parent component. Say if they click size 2= which is 14 i want the state of chosen object to be 14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
choice() {
    console.log(this.props.size);
}

{this.props.size && <DropdownItem onClick={() => this.choice()} className="bg-info">{this.props.size}</DropdownItem>}
```

If you want to change the size each time you click it, you have to use `state` and not `props`.

Comment: yes understand but i am trying to console log the proper size before i implement the state One sec let me try this.

Comment: Try using the arrow notation in `onClick`: `onClick={() => this.choice()}`

Comment: it works thank you why does this work is it because of the implicit return?

Comment: No, its because `this` depends on the object that is being called upon. If you use the arrow notation, `this` will be bound on the object, whereas if you don't use arrow notation, `this` is `null`. You can read more here: https://frontarm.com/james-k-nelson/when-to-use-arrow-functions/

Comment: Okay thank you. do you have any suggestions for using multiple props for instance size1 size 2 etc... without writing multiple function or switch statements. this.state.____

Comment: What do you mean? Each `DropDown` has multiple props?

Comment: Well each dropdown goes like this this.props.size this.props.size2 this.props.size3 all the way to 14 the function i created only works for this.props.size maybe i have to check to see if the .size matches the same prop?

Comment: Im trying to se the state to the property of size without writing multiple functions for each size

Comment: Maybe consider using an array of sizes?

Comment: I have an array this is just a snippet of much larger code. So what i came up with is just writing an inline set state method for each of the sizes like so  <DropdownItem
              onClick={() => {
                this.setState({ choice: this.props.size });
              }}

Comment: Hm, why do you need so many sizes? Maybe you should open another question to show all the code and I can take a look

Comment: Well mostly because of shoe sizes have 23 sized and sure i will one sec

Comment: new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57000079/trying-lessening-the-amount-of-functions-i-need-to-write-to-set-state-to-the-pro